# How to make event happen every two frames ? (processing)

Tags: processing

Basically I want an event to be triggered every 2 frames, so I'm using the frameCount with an if() statement, but I don't know how to specify "every two frames".

How do I specify that I want the event to take place whenever 2 is added to frameCount ?

Thanks !

Comment: Put `if(frameCount % 2 == 0) { ... }` around it. The modulus operator (`%`) returns the reminder of division. So, `0 % 2` will return `0`, `1 % 2 = 1`, `2 % 2 = 0` and `3 % 2 = 1` for example.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was modulo but didn't know how to use it !